# Django: how to assign a RawQuerySet to a Selectfield in forms

Tags: sql, django, django-forms, django-queryset

In a lot of situations I add a custom queryset to a selectfield in django form.

```
form.fields[fieldname] = model.objects.all()
```

Now I have a selectfield where I need to assign as choices the result of a RawQueryset.
I tried this (queryset is simplified):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = %s"
param.append (1234)
qs = model.objects.raw (sql, param)
form.fields[fieldname] = qs
```

The page is correctly displayed and the select field contains the data from the queryset.
When I try to save the form, form validation (form.is_valid()) throws the error:

*** Attribut error: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribut 'get'

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a `queryset` to a form field, like this:

```
# this is wrong
form.fields[fieldname] = qs
```

you need to define the field using one of the fields django has, like:

`form.fields[fieldname] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=qs)`

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django).